# Tar pattern match a file/folder present anywhere in a hierarchy

Tags: linux, pattern-matching, tar

I am doing this:

```
tar -C app/dir/ --strip-components=2 -xvf downloads/file.tar.gz
```

I want to extract only files and folders present anywhere inside hierarchy of name lets say "abc" (if file then it has no extension hence only "abc").
I have tried doing this:

`--wildcards "*/abc"` or `$( find -name "abc")`

I have read some answers and none of the accepted solutions worked.

Comment: What does the find spit out if you run it by itself?  That looks correct from here.

Comment: @StephenNewell Both wildcard, find ends up extracting everything.

Comment: cd app/dir; find -name "abc";  What does that list?  Since your find is in a subshell it'll run in the current directory, not app/dir.

Comment: Yep find -name "abc" returns stuff of name "abc", but I want to use patterns with tar, I want to extract only those which match my pattern. What will be the solution for this?

Comment: I haven't used the --wildcards option, so I'd suggest just running tar from app/dir.  Since you'll be in the proper subshell, the find should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match anywhere in the hierarchy, try including `--wildcards-match-slash`

```
$ tar -tf tmp.tar
tmp/
tmp/a/
tmp/a/b/
tmp/a/b/abc
tmp/a/c/
tmp/a/c/d/
tmp/a/c/d/abc
tmp/a/abc

$ tar --wildcards-match-slash --wildcards '*/abc' -xvf tmp.tar
tmp/a/b/abc
tmp/a/c/d/abc
tmp/a/abc
```